# error when I replace jquery 1.12.4 on 1.7

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting following error when I replaced jquery version 1.7 with 1.12.4 :

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href*=#]
at Function.fa.error (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2)
```

Following is my code, I am totally new in this arena dont know javascript much can anyone help me out with this ? :

```
$(window).load(function () {
    function filterPath(string) {
        return string.replace(/^\//, '').replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/, '').replace(/\/$/, '');
    }
    $('a[href*=#]').each(function () {
        if (filterPath(location.pathname) == filterPath(this.pathname) && location.hostname == this.hostname && this.hash.replace(/#/, '')) {
            var $targetId = $(this.hash),
            $targetAnchor = $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            var $target = $targetId.length ? $targetId : $targetAnchor.length ? $targetAnchor : false;

            if ($target) {

                $(this).click(function () {

                    //Hack collapse top navigation after clicking
                    topMenu.parent().attr('style', 'height:0px').removeClass('in'); //Close navigation
                    $('.navbar .btn-navbar').addClass('collapsed');

                    var targetOffset = $target.offset().top - 63;
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: targetOffset
                    }, 800);
                    return false;
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try changing `$('a[href*=#]')` to `$("a[href*='#']")`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for promt reply...it was helpful and solved the problem..but raised different error in console which is not affecting in the website but still it is throwing...

Comment: Thanks a lot for promt reply...it was helpful and solved the problem..but raised different error in console which is not affecting in the website but still it is throwing... [link](http://104.155.224.15/ifsi/)

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href='#'home]
    at Function.fa.error (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [W3C CSS validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input) your CSS selector is not valid:

```
a[href*=#] {
}
```

> Lexical error at line 1, column 10. Encountered: "]" (93), after : "#" *=] { }

You're missing quotes:

```
a[href*="#"] {
}
```

It probably stopped working on jQuery migration because newer versions use the (fastest) native CSS selector (`Element.querySelectorAll`), which is not tolerant to errors in the same way as the old pure JavaScript implementation provided by jQuery.

So try:

```
$('a[href*="#"]')
```

You may also get a similar error in this other selector:

```
$targetAnchor = $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
```

... should better be:

```
$targetAnchor = $('[name="' + this.hash.slice(1) + '"]');
```

... and might also need to escape `this.hash.slice(1)`, depending on what it's supposed to contain.

Similarly, this:

```
[href='#'portfolio]
```

... it should be:

```
[href='#portfolio']
```

You need to find the piece of code where you generate it and fix the syntax.

Absolutely all *Syntax error, unrecognized expression* errors you get pointing to a CSS selector have the same cause (invalid selector) and fix (correct selector syntax).

Comment: still getting Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href='#'portfolio]
    at Function.fa.error (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2)
    at fa.tokenize (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2) [link](http://104.155.224.15/ifsi/)

Comment: Unless I'm overlooking something it's exactly the same problem, isn't it?

Comment: no. I was using fancynews plugin by radykal..which was required jquery 1.12.4..due to older version plugin's popup functionality was not working..as soon as I done the changes you suggested it started working but still showing error. All of the elements are working though.

Comment: @VishwajeetJain I've just updated my answer, but I have the impression that I haven't been able to express myself correctly.